# after login redirect to another page

Tags: django, redirect, authentication

Im using django 1.10 embeded authentication. I want login redirect to another page and pass the variables too.
Ive made my views but i have all the time error 404. I read about "login-redirect-url" and default is accounts/profile. Ive made a folder inside my templates. Is this correct way? i store it in Django/myapp/myapp/templates/accounts/profile/home.html

error:"The current URL, accounts/profile/home.html, didn't match any of these."

```
views.py

    def home(request):
        username = None
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            username = request.user.username
            return redirect('accounts/profile/home.html',{'username': username})
        else:
            return redirect('/accounts/profile')


 myapp/ulrs.py

    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', views.home, name='home')
```

I changed settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

any suggestions will be welcome.If im doing this wrong please provide me an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u dont need to pass username in render request.
Here is an example:

view.py

```
def profile(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_staff:
       return redirect('/admin/')
    else:
       return render(request, 'accounts/profile/home.html',{})
```

home.html  ( store it myapp/myapp/templates/myapp/home.html)

```
Hello user:{{request.user.username}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Dariusz Niespodziany is valid, but what would be even better is to change your template. Your view will look like:

```
 def home(request):
      return redirect('/accounts/profile')
```

Then in your template (home.html) you can do stuff like this:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <h1> Hi {{request.user.username}} </h1>
{% else %}
    <h1> Hi stranger </h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ive tried  can u tell me plz where should i save my home. html

i edited settings

Comment: Your home.html should be within the app in the folder `templates`. if it's not there, create it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to render `accounts/profile/home.html` template with a context of `{'username': username}`.

```py
return render(request, 'accounts/profile/home.html', context={'username': username})
```

Comment: hey thanks for help
I tried but still have eror 404. Where should i save tamplate home?.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['login']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate (email=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                redirect_to = settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
                return redirect(redirect_to,{your varible })
```